# How do I upload an Excel sheet to a SQL table in a Lightswitch web client?

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have a lightswitch project in visual studio 2013, using vb.net.  I would like the user to be able to click a button and have lightswitch find an excel file, and upload that file to a sql table according to a pre-determined column mapping.

My preference was to use the Office Integration extension for visual studio, which I got working with VS 2013 by downloading it from this link: http://www.ge.tt/71iuRQv/v/0 
However, the documentation and examples for office integration seem to be very heavy on getting an excel spreadsheet into a display in the lightswitch web client, rather than into the sql data table, which is where I need it.   Here are the examples I've been following: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/07/18/new-and-improved-office-integration-pack-extension-for-lightswitch.aspx

Alternatively, I have an existing stored procedure, and I can request that the server call this stored proc by sending a web API extension from the client to the server.  I have this working already for other stored procs, according to examples from Beth Masi and Paul van Bladel.  (Stackoverflow won't let me post the links...)

The undesirable part of this approach is that the stored proc is old, and messy.

I've searched and searched, but have yet to find anyone approach this problem for VS 2013 with lightswitch.  Any useful advice?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the method detailed by [Matt Sampson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmattsampson/archive/2011/05/23/how-to-import-and-store-a-data-file.aspx) to store word files and it works very well. Since it just stores the raw binary it should handle Excel files just as well.

If you're creating the table in LightSwitch, use the `Binary` Type. If you use SQL create scripts use `varbinary(MAX)`.

You need to create a custom Silverlight dialog box to gain access to the `OpenFileDialog` object. Then open the file in as a `FileStream`.

Finally, you need to add a handler for the closed method of the control and then show the control to the user. Most likely done in a button. This needs to be done on the main dispatcher.

The code examples are in C# but I just used one of the many available translators out on the web and copy/pasted the VB.NET code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to consider shelling out to the DTSEXEC run-time to execute an SSIS package to perform the upload - especially if the target Excel spreadsheets have predefined layouts and content data types.

Even simpler, you might be able to use the [SQL Server BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms188365.aspx) command to get the job done - although that would require a SQL Client connection to your database.

HTH